# How can i use GeoTools/ProJ.4(Or Other api) to convert coordinate from HK80 GRID To latitude/longtitude?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, geotools, proj

how to convert a set of hk80 grid to lat/lon?

HK 1980 Grid is EPSG 2326, while Lat/Long WGS84 is EPSG 4326

Or is there any is more suitible for doing this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope that the following code can help you. I need to use GeoTools to achieve your purpose. Also, you need to insert the relevant northing and easting for epsg 2326. However, I still cannot solve the exception problem yet. In order to use this code properly, you need to download and import all GeoTools jars besides *gt-epsg-postgresql*.

```
package org.geotools.tutorial;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.io.File;

import org.geotools.data.FileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.factory.Hints;
import org.geotools.map.FeatureLayer;
import org.geotools.map.Layer;
import org.geotools.map.MapContent;
import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
import org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder;
import org.geotools.styling.SLD;
import org.geotools.styling.Style;
import org.geotools.swing.JMapFrame;
import org.geotools.swing.data.JFileDataStoreChooser;
import org.opengis.referencing.crs.CRSAuthorityFactory;
import org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem;
import org.opengis.referencing.operation.MathTransform;
import org.geotools.referencing.*;
/**
 * Prompts the user for a shapefile and displays the contents on the screen in a map frame.
 * <p>
 * This is the GeoTools Quickstart application used in documentationa and tutorials. *
 */
public class quickstart {

/**
 * GeoTools Quickstart demo application. Prompts the user for a shapefile and displays its
 * contents on the screen in a map frame
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Point2D.Double srcProjec = new Point2D.Double (836694.050, 819069.800);
        //Point2D.Double dstProjec = new Point2D.Double (132,37);
        // display a data store file chooser dialog for shapefiles
        //Hints hints = new Hints(Hints.FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER, Boolean.TRUE);
        //CRSAuthorityFactory factory = ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactory("EPSG", hints);
        //CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = factory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326");
        CRSAuthorityFactory   factory = CRS.getAuthorityFactory(true);
        CoordinateReferenceSystem srcCRS = factory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:2326");
        CoordinateReferenceSystem dstCRS = factory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326");
        boolean lenient = true; // allow for some error due to different datums
        MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(srcCRS, dstCRS, lenient);
        double[] srcProjec = {818039, 836361};// easting, northing, 
        double[] dstProjec = {0, 0};
        transform.transform(srcProjec, 0, dstProjec, 0, 1);
        System.out.println("longitude: " + dstProjec[0] + ", latitude: " + dstProjec[1]);

    }

}
```

Comment: Although the question has been posted half year ago,Thank you for the answer.I remembered i also use geotool to solve the problem(although i have use up 1 month to figure out the existence of the geotool api)

Comment: I am working something exactly the same, but in Android. It failed to compile as there are missing java lib in Android. Could you tell me which jar files are needed for the coordinate conversion?